# POSTMAN RESTCONF PUT AND POST FUNCTION ERROR

Tags: python, json, xml, postman

POST FUNCTION:

http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology

500 server error

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →file://
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →location
Content-Type →application/json
Server →Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

Server error:

2016-04-29 14:01:33,459 | INFO  | p684741745-10980 | RestconfImpl                     | 300 - org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector - 1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1 | Error creating data config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.AbstractDOMBrokerWriteTransaction.checkInstanceIdentifierReferencesData(AbstractDOMBrokerWriteTransaction.java:80)
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.AbstractDOMBrokerWriteTransaction.put(AbstractDOMBrokerWriteTransaction.java:73)
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.impl.BrokerFacade.postDataViaTransaction(BrokerFacade.java:330)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.impl.BrokerFacade.commitConfigurationDataPost(BrokerFacade.java:216)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.impl.RestconfImpl.createConfigurationData(RestconfImpl.java:871)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.impl.RestconfImpl.createConfigurationData(RestconfImpl.java:816)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.impl.StatisticsRestconfServiceWrapper.createConfigurationData(StatisticsRestconfServiceWrapper.java:152)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.impl.RestconfCompositeWrapper.createConfigurationData(RestconfCompositeWrapper.java:89)[300:org.opendaylight.netconf.sal-rest-connector:1.3.1.Beryllium-SR1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceObjectRule.accept(ResourceObjectRule.java:100)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)[248:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)[266:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)[266:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.17.0]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)[266:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.17.0]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[230:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:256)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)[294:org.apache.shiro.core:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)[294:org.apache.shiro.core:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)[294:org.apache.shiro.core:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)[293:org.apache.shiro.web:1.2.3]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[245:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.4]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)[245:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.4]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)[245:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.4]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[236:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]

========================

PUT FUNCTION:

http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology

Received 400 BAD REQUEST

```
{
  "errors": {
    "error": [
      {
        "error-type": "protocol",
        "error-tag": "malformed-message",
        "error-message": "Input is required."
      }
    ]
  }
}
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →file://
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →location
Content-Type →application/json
Server →Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

No error on the server

=================

Working Get output

```
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/yang.data+json
Server →Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding, User-Agent




{
  "topology": [
    {
      "topology-id": "pcep-topology",
      "topology-types": {
        "network-topology-pcep:topology-pcep": {}
      },
      "node": [
        {
          "node-id": "pcc://192.168.1.2",
          "network-topology-pcep:path-computation-client": {
            "reported-lsp": [
              {
                "name": "blue3_t16",
                "path": [
                  {
                    "lsp-id": 3,
                    "lspa": {
                      "local-protection-desired": false,
                      "hold-priority": 7,
                      "ignore": false,
                      "include-all": 0,
                      "include-any": 0,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "exclude-any": 0,
                      "tlvs": {},
                      "setup-priority": 7
                    },
                    "bandwidth": {
                      "ignore": false,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "bandwidth": "AAAAAA=="
                    },
                    "odl-pcep-ietf-stateful07:lsp": {
                      "remove": false,
                      "ignore": false,
                      "plsp-id": 17,
                      "delegate": true,
                      "administrative": true,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "odl-pcep-ietf-initiated00:create": false,
                      "sync": false,
                      "operational": "up",
                      "tlvs": {
                        "lsp-identifiers": {
                          "ipv4": {
                            "ipv4-tunnel-sender-address": "6.6.6.6",
                            "ipv4-extended-tunnel-id": "1.1.1.1",
                            "ipv4-tunnel-endpoint-address": "1.1.1.1"
                          },
                          "tunnel-id": 16,
                          "lsp-id": 3
                        },
                        "symbolic-path-name": {
                          "path-name": "Ymx1ZTNfdDE2"
                        },
                        "path-binding": {
                          "binding-value": "AAXc4AA=",
                          "binding-type": 0
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "ero": {
                      "ignore": false,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "subobject": [
                        {
                          "ip-prefix": {
                            "ip-prefix": "192.168.2.2/32"
                          },
                          "loose": false
                        },
                        {
                          "ip-prefix": {
                            "ip-prefix": "192.168.3.2/32"
                          },
                          "loose": false
                        },
                        {
                          "ip-prefix": {
                            "ip-prefix": "1.1.1.1/32"
                          },
                          "loose": false
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "blue3_t11",
                "path": [
                  {
                    "lsp-id": 63,
                    "lspa": {
                      "local-protection-desired": false,
                      "hold-priority": 7,
                      "ignore": false,
                      "include-all": 0,
                      "include-any": 0,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "exclude-any": 0,
                      "tlvs": {},
                      "setup-priority": 7
                    },
                    "bandwidth": {
                      "ignore": false,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "bandwidth": "AAAAAA=="
                    },
                    "odl-pcep-ietf-stateful07:lsp": {
                      "remove": false,
                      "ignore": false,
                      "plsp-id": 12,
                      "delegate": true,
                      "administrative": true,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "odl-pcep-ietf-initiated00:create": false,
                      "sync": false,
                      "operational": "up",
                      "tlvs": {
                        "lsp-identifiers": {
                          "ipv4": {
                            "ipv4-tunnel-sender-address": "6.6.6.6",
                            "ipv4-extended-tunnel-id": "1.1.1.1",
                            "ipv4-tunnel-endpoint-address": "1.1.1.1"
                          },
                          "tunnel-id": 11,
                          "lsp-id": 63
                        },
                        "symbolic-path-name": {
                          "path-name": "Ymx1ZTNfdDEx"
                        },
                        "path-binding": {
                          "binding-value": "AAXcQAA=",
                          "binding-type": 0
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "ero": {
                      "ignore": false,
                      "processing-rule": false,
                      "subobject": [
                        {
                          "ip-prefix": {
                            "ip-prefix": "1.35.1.2/32"
                          },
                          "loose": false
                        },
                        {
                          "ip-prefix": {
                            "ip-prefix": "1.1.1.1/32"
                          },
                          "loose": false
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "stateful-tlv": {
              "odl-pcep-ietf-stateful07:stateful": {
                "odl-pcep-ietf-initiated00:initiation": true,
                "lsp-update-capability": true
              }
            },
            "state-sync": "synchronized",
            "ip-address": "192.168.1.2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code and ask a specific question, not just paste in a bunch of error messages.

Comment: I am receiving 500 server error while trying to perform put operation on restconf

http://10.85.90.244:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology

Comment: I am performing put on http://10.85.90.244:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/pcep-topology
Content type is set to application/json
Authentication admin:admin

Comment: I'll say it again: you need to post your code and ask a specific question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure stack overflow is the right place to be asking this.   You'd probably be better to ask on the ODL BGP mailing list:

https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/bgpcep-users

Or you could try RTFM:

https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/BGP_LS_PCEP:Beryllium_Operations_Guide#Tunnel_Management_for_draft-ietf-pce-stateful-pce-07_and_draft-ietf-pce-pce-initiated-lsp-00

At any rate the brief summary is that the PCE-P topology is only present as operational data (not as config).   To add LSPs you issue an RPC call.